# How to fix disconnected line graphs in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to graph two variables on the same axis (each with a missing value - 1 at the beginning and 1 at the end) (see data).

I have attempted this using ggplot, but it orders the x-axis in a strange way, resulting in a gap in my line.

```
July <- mydat$July
August <- mydat$August
df=data.frame(months,July,August)

melt_df <- melt(data = df, id.vars = "months", measure.vars = c("July", "August"))

ggplot(melt_df, aes(x = months, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("July" = "Red", "August" = "Green")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("July"="solid", "August" = "solid"))
```

Here you can see what I mean with the missing values. Each variable has a rolling 12-month time period - as at the end of the previous month.

```
> melt_df
   months variable value
1  Jul-18     July  6.09
2  Aug-18     July  8.15
3  Sep-18     July  8.73
4  Oct-18     July  6.80
5  Nov-18     July  9.92
6  Dec-18     July 19.57
7  Jan-19     July 22.88
8  Feb-19     July 47.39
9  Mar-19     July 41.51
10 Apr-19     July 48.97
11 May-19     July 67.24
12 Jun-19     July 95.47
13 Jul-19     July    NA
14 Jul-18   August    NA
15 Aug-18   August  4.76
16 Sep-18   August  6.20
17 Oct-18   August  4.38
18 Nov-18   August  6.14
19 Dec-18   August 10.87
20 Jan-19   August 13.60
21 Feb-19   August 15.68
22 Mar-19   August 25.92
23 Apr-19   August 32.65
24 May-19   August 38.92
25 Jun-19   August 58.68
26 Jul-19   August 91.35
```

Output:

[image: ggplot output]

Answer (score 0):

```
melt_df %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>% ggplot(., aes(x = months, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("July" = "Red", "August" = "Green")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("July"="solid", "August" = "solid"))
```

This solution will just exclude those two values, though. You may not want this though.
Currently, `months` is being treated as a character/factor. If you want it to be ordered, chronologically, you will need to convert this to a `Date` format and then it will join the lines either side of the `NA` values when they're left in.

Comment: Thanks Rex, I am actually happy for those two values to be N/A. In terms of making ```months``` into a ```Date``` format, would one solution be using ```as.Date```

Comment: Yeah that's correct. You'll need to look into the options under the `format` argument to ensure it translates the abbreviated month and year properly.